# SVD calculation error from lapack function when using scikit-learn's Linear Discriminant Analysis class

Tags: python, scipy, lapack, svd, intel-mkl

I'm classifying 2-class, 1-D data using scikit-learn's [LDA](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/lda_qda.html) classifier in a machine learning pipeline I've created. The following exception occurred:

> ValueError: Internal work array size computation failed: -10

at the following line:

> LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.fit(X,y)

where X =  [-5e15, -5e15, -5e15, 5.7e16] and y = [0, 0, 0, 1], both float64 data-type

Additionally the following error was printed to console:

> Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 10 was incorrect on entry to DGESDD

After a quick Google search, dgesdd is a function in [LAPACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAPACK) which scikit-learn [relies upon](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/computing.html). The [dgesdd documentation](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d1/d7e/group__double_g_esing_gad8e0f1c83a78d3d4858eaaa88a1c5ab1.html) tells us that the function computes the [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) (SVD) of a real M-by-N matrix A.

Going back to the original exception, I found it was raised in [scipy.linalg.lapack.py](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/linalg/lapack.py) at the _compute_lwork function. This function takes as input a function, which in this case I believe is the dgesdd function. CTRL-F "-10" on the dgesdd documentation page gives the logic behind this error code, but I don't know Fortran so I'm not exactly sure what it means.

I want to bet that the SVD calculation is failing due to either (1) large values in X array, or (2) the fact that the 3 of the values in the X array are the exact same number.

I will keep reading into SVD and its limitations. Any insight on how to avoid this error would be tremendously appreciated.

Here is a screenshot of the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVRiy.png)

Comment: Could you please provide an example that fails. Recently people started having issues with scipy due to outdated BLAS routines. However, it was related to OpenBLAS, not MKL.

Comment: My apologies, but what specifically do you mean by "example"? I've added a screenshot to my post of the error that I received.

Comment: I mean, it is good to have a piece of code that can be easily copy-pasted and gives exactly the same error. Additionally, it's good to know what environment you have (library versions etc. )

Comment: Hi! I am having this issue too when incorporating LDA to sklearn's `SequentialForwardSelector`. Do you have any update or fix to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is the definition of DGESDD:

```
subroutine  dgesdd (JOBZ, M, N, A, LDA, S, U, LDU, VT, LDVT, WORK, LWORK, IWORK, INFO)
```

The error, that you have, indicates that the value that is passed to MKL's implementation of the routine for the 10th parameter, LDVT, the leading dimension of the `V**T` matrix does not comply with expecation of said routing.

This could be a bug in Intels implementation, rather unlikely, assuming that there is a battery on testing stress testing this routines, but not impossible. Which version of MKL is this? Or it's a bug in the LDA code, rather likely:

```
LDVT is INTEGER
      The leading dimension of the array VT.  LDVT >= 1;
      if JOBZ = 'A' or JOBZ = 'O' and M >= N, LDVT >= N;
      if JOBZ = 'S', LDVT >= min(M,N).
```

Would you please print M, N, LDA, LDU and LDVT?

If you set LDVT properly the workspace analysis will run just fine.

Comment: >Which version of MKL is this?
version=2019.1

Thank you for the explanation, Kaveh, I really appreciate the help! However, I am unsure how I would go about printing those values, coming from Python that is. 

One idea I have is to go to that scipy.linalg.lapack.py file (linked in original post) and then after the line where the DGESDD is called, which I think is:
wi = routine(*args, **kwargs)
I could print the *args and **kwargs to get those values you're requesting. Would also probably have to compile that .py source file.

What do you think of this approach?

Comment: The above is regardless of version. This is a standard and every vendor / open source project will have to implement the above interface identically.

Comment: It would be really helpful to see, what is handed to the function. You have the source code, right? Just rebuild it with the additional output.

Comment: Okay, so earlier, I pointed out the following line in lapack.py: wi = routine(*args, **kwargs). Printing these to console gave: args = (2, 0) and kwargs = {'compute_uv': True, 'full_matrices': 0}. Looking at the rest of the output, this is the first time args[1] was 0, it was always positive in every iteration before. Additionally, I tried printing "routine" and that is a Fortran object which I assume is the DGESDD function.

Answer (score 0):

regard to Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 10 was incorrect on entry to DGESDD problem. Actually this problem has been fixed in MKL v.2018 u4 ( Sep 2018). Here is the [link to MKL 2018 bug fix list](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-math-kernel-library-intel-mkl-2018-bug-fixes-list).
You may easier to check version of MKL you use by setting env variable MKL_VERBOSE=1 to the system environments and look at the output which will contain such kind info. 
E.x: 
MKL_VERBOSE Intel(R) MKL 2019.0 Update 2 Product build 20190118 for Intel(R) 64 architecture Intel(R) Advanced Vector Extensions (Intel(R) AVX) enabled processors, Lnx 2.80GHz lp64 intel_thread
MKL_VERBOSE ZGETRF(85,85,0x13e66f0,85,0x13e1080,0) 6.18ms CNR:OFF Dyn:1 FastMM:1 TID:0  NThr:20